# declaring two variables to calculate a function in a for loop in R

Tags: r

I need a for loop but isn't working.

I need to calculate a function with two variables in for loop. The function is

```
F(y, x) = 1 + y + y^2 + ... + y^x.
```

For example if

```
x = 4 
F(y, x) = 1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4
```

and so on.

```
> sum <- 1 
> for(i in 0:3){
+     for(y in 0:3){
+             sum <- sum + y ^ (i)
+     }
+ } 
print( sum )
```

[1] 61

This result is not correct. Should be ´40´

Comment: What are the two variables in the loop for? Do you want to compute the function for all combinations of `x = 1:10` and `y = 1:10`?

Comment: unclear: if `y` is a vector then the result `1 + y + y ^ 2 + y ^ x` will be a vector ... and is not storable in `y[i+1]`

Comment: Yes, in this example I want to calculate all the combinations of x and y = 1:10 and store it in a vector. But my final scope is to ask the user to introduce a x and a y and calculate the result.

Comment: Your function says `F(y, x) = 1 + y + y^2 + y^x` but your "For example" says: `x = 4;   
F(y, x) = 1 + y + y^2 + y^3 + y^4`   Your F would not include the y^3 term. Do you really mean `F(y,x) = sum(y^(0:x))` ?

Comment: Indeed, I really mean    `F(y,x) = sum(y^(0:x))`. 
I currently have no the ability to put this sum in code with a for loop. I've tryed a lot.

Comment: I've made some progress but the result should be ´40´and not ´61´. Someone to help me? I' ve edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result is correct: what you are computing with your code is the following sum:

```
1 +  (default value of sum)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + (i = 0)
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + (i = 1)
0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + (i = 2)
0 + 1 + 8 + 27 (i = 3)
```

which sums up to 61.

If you want a function which calculates

y^0 + y^1 +... + y^x, 
for integer values x, just try

```
sum(y^(0:x))
```

You don't need a for loop for that.

If you insist on a for loop you can try this

```
F <- function(x, y) {
  .sum <- 0
  for(i in 0:x) {
    .sum <- .sum + y^i
   }
  result(.sum)
}
```

Comment: Your code seems the wright solution. But if I call the function, for example, `F(3,3)` it returns nothing, I can't see no result. I don't know what could be the problem

Comment: add return(.sum) at the end of the function.